# Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.destroy] on Laravel form action

Tags: php, laravel

I have this error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.destroy] [URI: admin/{admin}]

That is the all view, and all variables,
i tried a lot but i don't know what's wrong if i change put the second parameter $info 
this error appears 
The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class=" table ">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Code</th>

                    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                    <th scope="col">Phone 2</th>
                    <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                    {{-- <th scope="col">email</th> --}}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($infos as $info)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $info->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $info->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $info->code }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $info->phone }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $info->phone2 }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="handleDelete ({{ $info->id }})">Delete
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    {{-- <td>{{ $info->email }}</td> --}}
                </tr>

                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <form action="{{ route('admin.destroy',['admin' => $info])}}" method="post" id="deleteInfoForm">
        @method('DELETE')
        @csrf
        <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModal"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModal">Delete Info</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p class=" text-center text-bold">Are your sure ?</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer ">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No , Go back</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes , Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

this is my delete function from AdminController

```
public function destroy(Info $admin)
    {
        // $info = Info::find($id);

        $admin->delete();

        // session()->flash('succuss', 'Info deleted successfully');
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
```

my routing list

```
| DELETE    | admin/{admin}          | admin.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route expects parameter 2 to be the model of the id used for route model binding

Add it to the action in the form

```html
<form action="{{ route('admin.destroy', ['admin' => $info]) }}"
```

#### Update

The form is outside the `foreach` loop and therefor `$info` is undefined

Pass the form inside the foreach instead

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class=" table ">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Code</th>

                <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                {{-- <th scope="col">email</th> --}}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($infos as $info)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $info->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $info->name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $info->code }}</td>
                <td>{{ $info->phone }}</td>
                <td>{{ $info->phone2 }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="handleDelete ({{ $info->id }})">Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
                {{-- <td>{{ $info->email }}</td> --}}
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <form action="{{ route('admin.destroy',['admin' => $info])}}" method="post" id="deleteInfoForm">
                    @method('DELETE')
                    @csrf
                    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModal"
                        aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModal">Delete Info</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p class=" text-center text-bold">Are your sure ?</p>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer ">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No , Go
                                        back</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes , Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Undefined variable: admin !

Comment: try `$info`, we don't know what your variable is named, post all of your view so we can tell

Comment: i added all view

Comment: What do you mean by "I added all view"?. Where is your controller logic where you return your blade view? Can you show us that? @Hesham

Comment: public function index()
    {
        $all = Info::latest()->get();
        return view('info.admin')->with('infos', $all);
    }

Comment: @Saly3301 no errors any more but not deleting also !

Comment: Hmmm, it should work, try finding the Info model by ID and deleting it

Comment: Hmmm, i found when i put the form inside the foreach the confirm button dosen't work , 
<script>
    function handleDelete(id){
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show')
        let form  = document.getElementById('deleteInfoForm')
        form.action = ''
    }
</script>

Comment: you don't have only one modal so you can't use #deleteModal

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the data you want to delete in your form opening:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.destroy', ['admin'=>$admin])}}" method="post" id="deleteInfoForm">
```

Before you do that, you have to pass the $admin variable to that view, in order to use it.

Comment: Undefined variable: admin

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because your route expects to get an admin variable (`admin/{admin}`), but it isn't there when you call `route` in `{{ route('admin.destroy')}}`. You should provide it as the second parameter of the `route` method, in the keyed array format.

Comment: Undefined variable: admin

Comment: To have access to a variable named `$admin` in your view you must first pass it to your view when you call the `view` method

Comment: i added all view

Comment: If you're set on that template then the option is to change your route and instead of getting admin as a route parameter use it as a common request parameter

Comment: i follow Saly's answer & i didn't have any error but it dosen't delete as well !